# Heroku running different Python versions remotely and locally

Tags: python, ubuntu, heroku

I just ran through the tutorial on Python and Heroku on my Ubuntu machine.  However, heroku insists on running Python 2.7 locally and Python 3.6 remotely.

I tried editing the `runtime.txt` to explicitly ask for Python 3.6 per the [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes).  However it's still running 2.7 locally.

When I run `pipenv --three` it creates the virtualenv and reports that it's choosing /usr/bin/python3, but when I run the app locally it's still running 2.7.

How can I force heroku to run the same version of Python both locally and remotely?

Comment: It's happened because you probably have `virtualenv` already installed for Py2.7. Please, activate your `env` and run `python`, on the top of window, you will see Py version

Comment: But, you can set `runtime.txt` for using Py2.7, but now it's a bad way